# DVI to HDMI/DisplayPort with 2560x1440

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I am having two 2560x1440 screens with HDMI, DisplayPort and mini-DisplayPort inputs (2x Dell UltraSharp U2715H). My goal is getting them to work with the following motherboard at their native resolution, without buying a dedicated GPU.
This is the motherboard: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/A88XMPLUS/specifications/

It says on the page:

```
Supports HDMI with max. resolution 4096 x 2160 @ 24 Hz / 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz*1
Supports DVI with max. resolution 2560 x 1600 @ 60 Hz
Supports RGB with max. resolution 1920 x 1600 @ 60 Hz
```

The HDMI-HDMI connection works with 2560x1440, but all the DVI to HDMI adapters I have lying around were limited to 2048x1152. I have tried DVI-D Single Link to HDMI and (supposedly) DVI-D Dual Link to HDMI cables and adapters.

**Are there any options to get this to work besides buying a dedicated graphcis card?**

Comment: `I have tried DVI-D single link to HDMI`. Single link is limited to 1920x1200. No need to try this one again. DVI to HDMI should have worked though.